# Как сделать, чтобы каждый пробел начинался новый элемент списка?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть строка:

```
test_string = '1 mode2 3param'
```

Как мне преобразовать эту строку в список так, чтобы каждый пробел в строке,
удалялся и вместо него начинался новый элемент списка?

На выходе должен получится такой список:

```
['1', 'mode2', '3param']
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы разбить строку Вам достаточно воспользоваться методом строки `split()`:

```
test_string = '1 mode2 3param'

result = test_string.split()

print(result)  # ['1', 'mode2', '3param']
```

## Немного о методе `split()`

Метод строки `split()` разбивает строку на части (слева направо) и возвращает эти части списком (`list`).

Метод принимает следующие НЕОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫЕ аргументы:

`sep=` - принимают строку, которая будет является разделителем. По умолчанию `None` из-за чего строка разбивается по пробелАМ.

Пример:

```
'aaa,bbb,ccc'.split(',')   # Результат: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
'aaa,bbb,ccc'.split(sep=',')   # Результат: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

`maxsplit=` - принимает целочисленное значение, количество разбиений, которое требуется выполнить. По умолчание `-1`, что означает бесконечное.

Пример:

```
'aaa,bbb,ccc'.split(',', 1)   # Результат: ['aaa', 'bbb,ccc']
'aaa,bbb,ccc'.split(sep=',', maxsplit=1)   # Результат: ['aaa', 'bbb,ccc']
```